# What does ClipRect do in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Could you please explain to me what ClipRect is in Delphi?
I read the documentation, and i did not comprehend it well.
What does the following line do?

```
     FillRect(ClipRect);
```

Comment: Without context how do we know what this code actually is. [mcve]

Comment: I'd say the [FillRect documentation](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Graphics_TCanvas_FillRect.html) makes it clear that its parameter is a [TRect](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Types.TRect) rectangle.

Comment: Obviously `ClipRect` is a rectangle, probably used for clipping.

Comment: I'm willing to bet the confusion leads from the use of the `with` statement :-/

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you mean [`TCanvas.ClipRect`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCustomCanvas.ClipRect), the documentation says:

> Read-only property that specifies the boundaries of the clipping rectangle.
>
> Use `ClipRect` to determine where the canvas needs painting. `ClipRect` limits the drawing region of the canvas so that any drawing that occurs at coordinates outside the `ClipRect` is clipped and does not appear in the image.
>
> When handling a form's `OnPaint` event, the canvas's `ClipRect` property is set to the rectangle that needs to be painted. Portions of the image that do not overlap the `ClipRect` do not need to be drawn. Thus, `OnPaint` routines can use the value of `ClipRect` to optimize painting, speeding the overall performance of the application.

A clipping region ensures that all painting is limited to that region. So if you set a clipping region that only covers parts of the canvas, any painting *outside* the clipping region will **not** be performed.

The documentation links to a [simple example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/ClipRect_(Delphi)). This also uses [`TCanvas.FillRect()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries//en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.FillRect), which fills the given rectangle with the current brush (colour or pattern).